# Limit bandwidth for a cisco switch port

Tags: networking, cisco, bandwidth-throttling

I am using Cisco Catalyst 2960-CG Series switch. I want to limit the bandwidth of my ports to 100 kbps. But not able to do so. Tried doing so by setting up a VLAN but still not able to achieve the desired limit. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Switch(config)# interface FastEthernet 0/1
Switch(config-if)# srr-queue bandwidth limit 90
```

Source:
[https://www.techrepublic.com/article/limit-bandwidth-on-a-cisco-catalyst-switch-port/#:~:text=The%2090%20sets%20the%20outbound,the%20port%20to%2010%20Mb](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/limit-bandwidth-on-a-cisco-catalyst-switch-port/#:%7E:text=The%2090%20sets%20the%20outbound,the%20port%20to%2010%20Mb).